# php pagination on second page not working

Tags: php, mysqli

```
            $dwdb=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dw");
            //this is my page number
            $page=(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']>0)?$_GET['page']:1 ;
            //this is my cat_id
            $new=(isset($_GET['year']) && $_GET['year']>0)?$_GET['year']:1 ;

        $perpage=2;
        $limit=($page > 1)?($page*$perpage)-$perpage:0;

        $query=mysqli_query($dwdb,"select *from movies where y_id='$new' limit {$limit},{$perpage}");
        while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    $id=$result['m_id'];
                    $name=$result['title'];
                    $img=$result['image'];


    echo"<div><a href='downloadpage.php?yc=$id'>$id.....$name<br><img src='i/image/$img' style='height:200px;width:200px;'/></a></div>";

            }
$query1=mysqli_query($dwdb,"select *from movies where y_id='$new'");
$total=mysqli_num_rows($query1);
$pages=ceil($total/$perpage);

echo "<a href='index1.php?page=1'>".'First Page'."</a>";
for ($i=1; $i<=$pages;$i++){

    echo "<a href='index1.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";

    };
  echo        "<a href='index1.php?page=$pages'>Last page</a>";
```

That is my code. The problem is that on my second page i have result of first $new variable .......................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Can you give more information on what is "not working". Any error/debug output messages?

Comment: I've deleted my answer. The reason being `$new` value is not being manipulated in your code, so how do you expect a *different* value to appear in the subsequent pages? Furthermore, you never used this `$new` variable in the pagination links, so how do you expect a new value to appear in the subsequent pages?

Comment: my problem is that when i click on year id one then it show the exact result on all pages but when i click on year id two then it show first page according to my wish but when i go for second page it goes on first year id.imean year id one...

Comment: ...because you don't send the year at the page-link...

Comment: `echo "<a href='index1.php?page=".$i."&year=".$new."'>".$i."</a> ";`

Comment: @waqarmumtaz I've undeleted my answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... i have a problem that on my second page i have result of first $new variable

That's because you're not including `$new` variable in the pagination links. So every time you go to 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ... page, you'll get the same `$new` value as `1`, and that's because of this statement,

```
$new=(isset($_GET['year']) && $_GET['year']>0)?$_GET['year']:1 ;
```

Include this variable in the pagination links so that you could get it's value in the subsequent pages. So your *pagination links* section would be like this:

```
// your code

echo "<a href='index1.php?page=1&year=".$new."'>".'First Page'."</a>";
for ($i=1; $i<=$pages;$i++){
    echo "<a href='index1.php?page=".$i."&year=".$new."'>".$i."</a> ";
}
echo "<a href='index1.php?page=".$pages."&year=".$new."'>Last page</a>";
```

Comment: @waqarmumtaz You're welcome. ;-) Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

for pagination use this code in file with name: view-paginated.php

```
$per_page = 10;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
{
$show_page = $_GET['page'];

if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
{
$start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
$end = $start + $per_page;
}

else
{
$start = 0;
$end = $per_page;
}

}

else
{
$start = 0;
$end = $per_page;
}

echo "<p><a href='view.php'>show all</a> | <b>page:</b> ";

for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{
echo "<a href='view-paginated.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
}

for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
{
if ($i == $total_results) { break; }
echo  mysql_result($result, $i, 'YOUR COLUMN') ;
}
```